# how to show the textbox value of one vf page in another vf page as a label

Tags: visualforce, controller, pagereference, id

i am beginner in salesforce, i have made one vf page there is textbox and button in that page on button click i want to show textbox value of my textbox as a label in another vf page on button click.kindly give the suggestion.first vf page-

```
<apex:page Standardcontroller="redirectobj__c" extensions="pageclass">
 <apex:form >
     <apex:pageblock >
         <apex:pageblocksection >
             <apex:pageblocksectionItem >
                Name:<apex:inputField value="{!redirectobj__c.name__c}" id="recid"/>
             </apex:pageblocksectionItem>
         </apex:pageblocksection> 
         <apex:pageblockbuttons >
         <apex:commandButton value="gotopage" action="{!gone}"/>
          </apex:pageblockbuttons>  
     </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

second vf page--

```
<apex:page Standardcontroller="redirectobj__c" extensions="pageclass">
    <form>
        <apex:pageblock >
          there is output: <apex:outputlabel value="{!redirectobj__c.name__c}"/>  
         </apex:pageblock>
    </form>
</apex:page>
```

controller---

```
public with sharing class pageclass {

    public String pageclass { get; set; }
    public string name{get;set;}

    public PageReference gone() {

        redirectobj__c lrc=new redirectobj__c();
        pagereference newpage=new pagereference('/apex/pagename?id='+oppid)
        return null;
    }
    public pageclass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    Id oppid;
    oppId=ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('oppId');

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small change in your controller

Use setRedirect false Also check few changes I made in your controller.

> If set to false, the redirect is a server-side forward that preserves
>   the view state if and only if the target page uses the same controller
>   and contains the proper subset of extensions used by the source page.

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_PageReference_setRedirect.htm)

```
public with sharing class pageclass {

    public String pageclass { get; set; }
    public string name{get;set;}
    private redirectobj__c objRedirect ; 

    public pageclass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
     objRedirect = (redirectobj__c)controller.getRecord();

    }
    public PageReference gone() {

        redirectobj__c lrc=new redirectobj__c();
        pagereference newpage=new pagereference('/apex/pagename?id='+objRedirect.name__c);
        newpage.setRedirect(false);
        return newpage;
    }

}
```